# JQM external pages strange behaviour

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a html file with three pages defined in it. I was experimenting with making pages external and loading them using `$.mobile.loadPage` and all of the sudden everything stopped making sense!

First I created two files, one with mainpage and the other with two other pages in it. I noticed the external files have to contain a single page! So I created three files, main file with mainpage and all scripts. 2ndpage and 3rdpage and used `$.mobile.loadPage` to load page 2 and 3.

So far so good and all worked. Then I noticed my back buttons won't work! `data-rel="back"` and I tried everything from setting the external flag to using reload and so on but back wasn't working. Then I used browser's back to just get to my page and noticed the link that took me to page 2 from main page or the link that took me to page 3 from page two also aren't working anymore! No error messages and nothing, even when I debug my code all seems to be fine however `$.mobile.changePage` is not working after the first transition to a page!

I put back everything in one file and all work fine again! So I'm sure this has something to do with ajax loading of the files and pages but I can't figure it out what is the correct way of doing this so the behaviour of all three pages on the same file and having them on three separate files would be the same.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Pls post code of how you used to navigate between the 3 pages (external).

Comment: Omar, to navigate to a page in all cases I use  $.mobile.changePage("#pageA","flip",true,true); and for back function the href is # and data-rel is set to back. Thx for looking into this.

Comment: You're question is about multi-page template (page1.html, page2.html etc...).

Comment: Correct, in my page first I use $.mobile.loadPage to load page1.html and page2.html and then use $.mobile.changePage("#page1","flip",true,true); to navigate to loaded pages which works fine on first call all the time and won't work on consequence calls without any error message!

Comment: Pages aren't cached, use changePage with URL not page id even after loading them.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the issue, I followed what you suggested and the forward links started working however the backward links (rel-back) is not working as expected and when it goes to the previous page the data is lost. I need the pages to be in the same context. I guess what I was hoping was to use loadpage the same way I can use page including in JSP. Maybe this is not possible?!

Comment: its better to use single-page template in case you want all pages in same context.